# Does the size of FlowFile affect I/O

Tags: apache-nifi

What would be the consideration factors for the size of the FlowFile? Does it affect I/O and is it the bigger the better if sufficient memory is provided?  because NIFI persists per FlowFile from disk to memory?

Especially for Kafka Consumer Processor, it contains a property called `Message Demarcator`. With the setting one FlowFile can contain many events, and without it, one FlowFile only contains one event. Let's say would it be more performant if FlowFile contains 1000 json objects than 1 json object?

The part confuses me especially is this document
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/21011/how-i-extract-attribute-from-json-file-using-nifi.html

It says to store json value in `FlowFile` Attribute which means it processes one Json Object per `FlowFile`, and one `FlowFile` contains one Json Object. Because if a FlowFile has more than one json object, it would have to create as many attributes as the json objects. for example, every json object has a timestamp field called `occurred_at`, it would then have to create `occurred_at_1` `occurred_at_2` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will see significant improvement in performance if you can keep many messages together in a single flow file. For example, lets say you consume 1 million messages from Kafka and have one message per flow file, this means 1 million writes to the flow file repo, 1 million provenance events, 1 million objects on the heap, etc. If you instead had 1 flow file with 1 million messages, it would be 1 write to the flow file repo, 1 provenance events, 1 object on the heap (not the content).

When you have many messages together in a single flow file you can't really extract the value of a field to an attribute, since as you pointed out there would be different values for the field for each record. You can work around this by using the record processors which let you process records in place. For example, instead of EvaluateJsonPath + RouteOnAttribute, you can just use PartitionRecord to separate the messages based on the value of a field.